# I need to open a new window in the background with JavaScript, and make sure the original is still focused

Tags: javascript, html

I have a window I'm opening with a Javascript function:

```
function newwindow() 
{ 
window.open('link.html','','width=,height=,resizable=no'); 
}
```

I need it that once the new window opens that the focus returns to the original window.
How can I do that?
And where do I put the code - in the new window, or the old one?
Thanks!

Comment: WELL, I have a test where I want to click one button but have 12 different windows (Post data response from server)  to open to view the layouts and compare them quickly/easily, so far I can only get the last getelementbyId to bind onClick event, I think its because the window loses focus and cannot locate the other IDs on the  result window

Comment: @DanMcGrath - there are definitely legitimate uses for this. In my case, we have search results for "deals" that link to outside vendor webpages. One of these vendors (called Abenity), gives us a unique login url for every user, and this user must be logged into Abenity before being able to view any of their deals. Now, we can't do a AJAX get on this Abenity login url, and we want to keep the user on our page... So, our best option is to open the login window as a "pop-under", keep the user on our page, then redirect the user to the deal on the Abenity page (where they are now logged in).

Comment: Sometimes good UX has to trump good programming :P

Comment: @DanMcGrath I'm getting data from a web service (http://services.tropicos.org/), and want two things: 1) part of the data appears in the current window; 2) a page of the service site opens in the background. So, that's a reason for using this technique...

Comment: You want something which is not possible, at least not with these "modern" browsers.

Answer (score 16):

This is known as a 'pop-under' (and is generally frowned upon... but I digress).. It should give you plenty to google about

You probably want to do something like:

```
var popup = window.open(...);
popup.blur();
window.focus();
```

Which should set the focus back to the original window (untested - pinched from google). Some browsers might block this technique.

Comment: I tried using the blur() thing, but it didn't work so well in Firefox, so I guess that should work better - I just wasn't sure how to refer back to the original window.
I also saw something about window.opener.focus() = does anyone know how I would use that?

Comment: Popup blockers have progressed a bit. I'm not surprised that browsers will block this technique - it's almost always used for evil.

Comment: Most of site telling about same trick to open new window in background, but none of them working. Des any other trick to do so from JavaScript/jQuery etc.

Comment: @DemvenWeir - it's likely now being blocked by browsers.

Answer (score 7):

If [Albert's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure-the/23733362#23733362) doesn't work for you and you actually want the window visible, but to be opened behind the current window, you can try opening a new tab in the opener window and closing it right away, this will bring the focus back to the opener window.

```
window.open('link.html','','width=,height=,resizable=no');  
window.open().close();
```

However, I believe whether the second window opens in a tab or a new window depends on your browser settings.

Please don't use "pop-unders" for evil.

Answer (score 6):

After calling window.open, you may try to use

```
window.resizeTo(0,0); 
window.moveTo(0,window.screen.availHeight+10);
```

this way can not really open window in background, but works in similar way. Chrome works fine, did not try other browser.

Comment: wow, genius.  also,then you can use `window.close();` in that popup page too (if you own that page).

Comment: @tazo you can also use close() even if you don't own that page, you just need to save the window in a variable when you open it
    w = window.open(...);
    .... 
    w.close();

Answer (score 2):

You can use either
"blur"  or
"focus"  to do that required action.

**"blur"**

```
function newwindow()  
{  
    var myChild= window.open('link.html','','width=,height=,resizable=no');  
    myChild.blur();
}
```

**"focus"**

```
function newwindow()  
{  
    window.open('link.html','','width=,height=,resizable=no');  
    window.focus();
}
```

Put the code in your parentWindow (i.e. the window in which you are now)

Both will work.

Comment: It works for me in the FireFox,what type of problem have you obeserved.
Thanks.

Comment: You're right - not sure that code will work in Chrome though.
I'll try it - thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr - in 2022 - `ctrl`/`cmd` clicking on a **button** and `window.open(url, "_blank")` in a javascript button handler's `for` loop will open multiple tabs in the background **in Chrome**.

I'm looking for this as of 2022 and none of the answers here worked (here and everywhere else I looked). My use case is clicking a button in a (progressive) web app which opens deep links to items in a list in background tabs (i.e. not "for evil").

It never occurred to me that ctrl/cmd + clicking on the button would open tabs in the background, but it does just as if the user clicked on an anchor tag itself directly - but only in Chrome. Combined with Chrome's relatively recent [tab grouping feature](https://blog.google/products/chrome/manage-tabs-with-google-chrome/), this can be very useful inside PWAs.

```
const isMozilla =
  window?.navigator?.userAgent?.toString().toLowerCase().includes('firefox') ?? false;
for (let index = 0; index < urls.length; index++) {
  const url = isMozilla ? urls.reverse()[index] : urls[index];
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Note: I `reverse()` the array on Mozilla to get the order of newly created tabs as the user would expect them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use '_self'. It will be stay to the same page an

```
window.open(url, '_self');
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Your answer opens a new url in the same tab. The question was how to open a new tab in the background, so the original tab keeps focus.