# Stay on Current Tab while using window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a window in another tab in my code, but the problem is the focus shifts to new tab opened, I want the focus to remain on the current window

I have searched for it, but have not got any solution, the focus() function is as I have understood is useful when opening popups.

I am using : window.open() function

```
window.open("myurl");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure

Comment: that will be a popup , I want the url to be opened in another tab not a complete other window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm also [check this](http://richardneililagan.com/2011/08/jquery-open-external-links-in-new-tabs/)

You can't directly control this, because it can be configured by the user. You might try "_newtab" which might work for Firefox but really you shouldn't rely on a new tab being opened. The user may have their browser settings set to open a new tab when a popup window is opened or it may show up as a popup. It just all depends on the browser settings.