# dispatchEvent not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I was trying to open a new tab inside my JavaScript. It works as expected in Chrome, but when it comes to Firefox it does nothing.I know `window.open()` can be used to open a tab, but my intention is to keep the focus on the current page. I have spent my entire day searching for a fix for this, but all I could see is people claiming it is a bug in Firefox. I wanted to know if there is any work around for this. Here is the piece of code I am using.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = popup_url;//this comes from the function's argument
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         true, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox

Comment: Yes. I have seen that post and 4 more, but none of those solutions worked for me.So I am posting a new question here.

Comment: Well clearly there is no easy fix. Firefox just simply does not allow this kind of behavior. Even trying to ['pop-under'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure) doesn't work in my firefox

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your suggestions, but I really want to fix this issue somehow, it is quite important.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working function ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809057/how-do-i-programmatically-click-on-an-element-in-firefox#answer-22469115)):

```
function click(node){
  var evt=new MouseEvent('click',
     {'view':window,'bubbles':true,'cancelable':true});
  node.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```