# I want to open link on another tab but do not want to lose focus from my current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, anchor

I want to open link on another tab but do not want to lose focus from my current tab.
I have tried enough doing it but unable to execute this behavior.

Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hi, did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background before asking? :)

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure-the