# How to stay in a tab while opening a new one (open a file)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, anchor

I have a link to open a `pdf` in a browser. But, It gets focused on the new tab (the tab with the `pdf`. How to prevent this behavior?

This is the link:

```
<strong><a style="text-decoration:none" class='row_link' href='javascript:void(0)' target="_blank" onFocus="false">Open File</a></strong>
```

This is the jquery:

```
$("#myTable tbody").on('click','.row_link', function(e) {
    var no_s    = $(this).find('.filename').val().replace(/\//g , '');
    var b_url   = $('#base_url').val()+"assets/uploads/file/";

    var url     = b_url + no_s;
    window.open(url);
});
```

I've tried adding `onfocus="false"` in the anchor. But, It's no effect

Comment: You cannot do this on the browser. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<strong><a style="text-decoration:none" class='row_link' href='https://github.com/caiyongji' onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">Open File</a></strong>
</html>
```

Comment: It's still focused on the pdf tab

Comment: Now try this. It works. Don't run in this page, copy out and then perform it.

Comment: The new tab is not opened the pdf. It open the previous page in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called the "pop under".

Basically you need to use window.blur() on the newly opened window to lose the focus and then refocus on your existing tab.

```
$("#myTable tbody").on('click','.row_link', function(e) {
var no_s    = $(this).find('.filename').val().replace(/\//g , '');
var b_url   = $('#base_url').val()+"assets/uploads/file/";

var url     = b_url + no_s;
var newWindow = window.open(url);
newWindow.blur();
window.focus();
});
```

[Relevant Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure-the)

Comment: It's still focused on the pdf tab

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the behaviour of opening background tabs, try the following code which is an example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background/11389138#11389138)

For example in your jquery;

```
$("#myTable tbody").on('click','.row_link', function(e) {
    var no_s    = $(this).find('.filename').val().replace(/\//g , '');
    var b_url   = $('#base_url').val()+"assets/uploads/file/";

    var url = document.createElement("a");
    url.href = b_url + no_s;
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Let me know if it helps or if you find a problem

Comment: It's still focused on the pdf tab.

Comment: Now the pdf is fail to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need is, you don't want to show the newly opened tab to the user. This cannot be done as @Rex suggested, but what can be done as an alternative is, you can open a popup window and minimise it as soon as you want..

Please have a look on below code :

**Parent Page**

```
<a href="javascript:openPopUP();">Click to open popup</a>
```

**Child Page**

```
      <body onLoad="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);" 
      onFocus="setTimeout('window.blur()', 1000);">
```

You can change the time 1000 to what you want.

You can use this on child to keep focus on parent page

```
window.parent.opener.focus();
```

Comment: I do not want to open any window. Beacuse, User may open multiple pdf. If each pdf is openend in a new window, user may get lag on ther computer