# ctrl+click always opens new tab in foreground

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using code below to simulate mouse click on the button:

```
someButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { ctrlKey: true }));
```

But it keeps opening in new tab with the focus on new tab.
I want it to behave just like the manual usage of ctrl+mouseClick when new tab opens in background.

There is no url under this button, it's submit button under the form with POST request.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This would behaviour is probably intentional so that if a page is opened it is not hidden in the background

Comment: There is a URL associated with the button if it posts a form: the form's `action` attribute. Browser makers are wise to the tricks spammers and the rest have come up with to create pop-unders and the like. You can't simulate everything a user can do; sometimes a user (or at least a process external to the browser) has to perform the action.

Comment: Is 'someButton' truly a button or an `<a>` element?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey
 , the form has the action="/somepage/anotherpage"
so if it's not possible to run the script to open that in new tab in background, is there any workaround for that? pop-ups are allowed in my broweser

Comment: @paddotk 
yes, it is truly a button with submit type inside the form

Comment: What might work is `event.preventDefault()` where `event` is the passed event object in the callback. The code would be something like `someButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { ctrlKey: true }), myListener);` where myListener` is the callback function.

Comment: Is there any workaround for something that's not possible? No. It's not possible. You could theoretically have your popup post a message back to your main window once it is open, and your main window could set focus on itself, but that seems like a lot of work for so little gain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open new tab in background leaving focus on current tab - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760490/open-new-tab-in-background-leaving-focus-on-current-tab-chrome)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - it's not answering as I'm using mainly Opera, however I would prefer to have a script solution without additional extensions/files. There must be a way to bypass this focusing...

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe worth noting that `ctrl-click` does not have the same behavior on all platforms; even if this worked, it would only work for a subset of users. (The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) contain a fun example of this; they do note which literal button `Ctrl` maps to on a mac... but the demo is unusable because ctrl-click triggers a (native, non-browser) context menu, preventing the click event even reaching the demo panel.  (For OSX you'd want to look for `metaKey`, not `ctrlKey`.)

If you *reeeeeeeally* want to do this, check `navigator.platform` first to determine whether to use `ctrlKey` or `metaKey` (and possibly something else on other platforms than desktop mac or windows, I'm not certain.)

To open new tabs in the background, I believe you can trigger a `focus` event on the originating window after the secondary tab/window is opened.   (I would strongly recommend against it, though; modifying expected, standard browser behavior is not great UX, and would likely have accessibility implications.)